# jQuery dataTables CSV server data

Tags: jquery, csv, xmlhttprequest, datatables

I've got a difficult one where I have one system generating CSV files to a directory on my web server, but I need to display that data using dataTables /jquery.  I can't change the CSV data into JSON because other systems consume that data right now.

I've tried using XMLHttpRequest to get my csv file & fire it through a callback conversion function before providing the converted data to dataTables.  The problem I find is that invariably the GET for the CSV isn't complete before the DOM is ready so I get an empty dataTable.  I've not seen a way to tell dataTables to reload the data - maybe I've missed that??

I've taken a look at using fnServerData in the dataTable to replace the XMLHTTPRequest.  But in this case I don't seem to be able to get hold of the raw data - it seems to be trying to interpret it as JSON all the time.

- Has anyone handled server side CSV data going into dataTables successfully?
- Any views on the best approach to continue with - XMLHttpRequest & maybe some kind of refresh call to dataTables??
- How can I get the raw CSV data if I use fnServerData??  I should also mention my CSV includes a header row so I've got to remove that regardless.

Comment: Add a second page to the server which serves the same data as JSON rather than CSV.

Answer (score 1):

In the [dataTables forum some has posted a message](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/12756#Comment_12756) about how they have been able to load a CSV file into the dataTables using the csv2table plugin.